# Inserting text using if else statement in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am trying to insert the text 'Active'/'Deactive' depending on whether the value of jobs.active is True or False. My code gives no output though. Please help:

```
 <b> Status</b>: <script type="text/javascript">
                    if ({{job.active}}) {
                       document.write("<b>Active</b>")
                     }
                   else {
                       document.write("<b>Deactive</b>")
                    }
        </script>
```

Comment: `{{job.active}}` is coming from Django? Shouldn't you just be doing the if/else on the Django side? `{% if job.active %}` or something

Comment: I would prefer doing it in the front end side since it has some other functionality too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the condition with Django, not Javascript.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Something like this:

```
{% if job.active %}
    <b>Active</b>
{% else %}
    <b>Deactive</b>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`True` cause an error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: True is not defined`.
It will works:

```
if ("{{job.active}}" === "True") {
   document.write("<b>Active</b>")
 } else {
     document.write("<b>Deactive</b>")
}
```

Comment: Doing this in Django side seems to be better.